# dynamic inputs with keyup()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a problem with a script with 3 inputs

While the user is typing a script should calculate some results.. It works almost as it should exept when the `Sale` input has a value and the user edit the `Avance` input, the script doesn't return the results?

http://jsfiddle.net/pxaYf/

```
<div id="tst" style="border:1px solid black; background:white; width:100px; height:100px"></div>

Cost = <input id="inp_cost" type="text" /><br>
Avance = <input id="inp_avance" type="text" /><br>
Sale = <input id="inp_sale" type="text" /><br>

$(function(){
    var calc = function(){
        var Calc = new Calc_avance();
        Calc.cost = $('#inp_cost').val();
        Calc.avance = $('#inp_avance').val();
        Calc.sale = $('#inp_sale').val();
        Calc.calc();

        $('#tst').html('<div>cost = '+Calc.cost+'</div><div>avance = '+Calc.avance+'</div><div>sale = '+Calc.sale+'</div>');

        return Calc;
    };

    var calc_cost = function(){
        var Calc = calc();
    };

    $('#inp_cost').change(calc_cost)
        .keyup(calc_cost);

    var calc_avance = function(){
        var Calc = calc();
    };

    $('#inp_avance').change(calc_avance)
        .keyup(calc_avance);

    var calc_sale = function(){
        var Calc = calc();
    };

    $('#inp_sale').change(calc_sale)
        .keyup(calc_sale);
});

function Calc_avance(){
    this.cost = 0;
    this.avance = 0;
    this.sale = 0;

    this.calc = function(){
        this.cost = parseFloat(this.cost.replace(',', '.'));
        this.avance = parseFloat(this.avance.replace(',', '.'));
        this.sale = parseFloat(this.sale.replace(',', '.'));

        if(!isNumber(this.cost)){
            this.cost = 0;
        }

        if(!isNumber(this.avance)){
            this.avance = 0;
        }

        if(!isNumber(this.sale)){
            this.sale = 0;
        }

        if(this.cost){
            if(this.sale){
                this.avance = (this.sale - this.cost) / this.sale * 100;
            }

            if(this.avance){
                this.sale = this.cost / (100 - this.avance) * 100;
            }
        }
        else{
            this.avance = 0;
        }

        if(this.avance < 0){
            this.avance = 0;
        }
    };
}

function isNumber(n){
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well on your script not returning a value do you mean it doesn't POST a value? Your inputs have no names, just IDs, so they will not POST at all.

Further, I see interesting recursion issues with your code.  calc_avance calls calc which calls Calc_avance, its a complex mess.

All in all I think the biggest thing you could do is scrap what you have and start over.  It looks like what you're trying to do is really simple and you just over complicated the problem

Comment: where do you see that recursion? :)

Comment: yes, it could be made a bit more simple, but its a part of something more which I have left out